# Garbage collection when using clone

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Im writing a program which uses the following clone() method:

```
circuit* circuit::clone()
{
    return new circuit(*this);
}
```

It is used in my copy constructor as so:

```
circuit::circuit(const circuit& circ)
{
    rank = circ.rank;
    branch_info = circ.branch_info;
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < circ.components.size(); i++) {
        components.push_back(circ.components[i]->clone());
    }
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < circ.branches.size(); i++) {
        branches.push_back(circ.branches[i]->clone());
    }
}
```

My question is, using this implementation, how do I ensure that there are no memory leaks as I cannot delete them within this function. Is there a way to implement it in the destructor or something along them lines?

Comment: Return a `std::unique_ptr<circuit>` instead of a `circuit*`

Comment: In modern C++, there are a variety of smart pointers and containers you can use.  The `std::unique_ptr` is my first-best-choice smart pointer.  I suggest that *raw pointers* only be used as **non-owning pointers**.

Comment: FYI, standard C++ does not have Garbage Collection; if you want it, you'll have to implement your own.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Technically, C++ does have optional garbage collection until C++23 though I don't know of any implementation that chooses to support it. Ex. : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/gc/declare_reachable

Comment: BTW: Does your data structure form a graph or a tree? Because unique pointers wouldn't be suitable if e.g. two circuits contain the same component.

Answer (score 1):

Modern C++ (meaning C++11 upwards) comes with a unique_ptr type that does exactly that. Use it like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<circuit> circuit::clone() const
{
    return std::make_unique<circuit>(*this);
}

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<circuit>> components, branches;

circuit::circuit(const circuit& circ)
: rank(circ.rank),
  branch_info(circ.branch_info)
{
    for(const std::unique_ptr<circuit>& component: circ.components)
        components.push_back(component->clone());
    for(const std::unique_ptr<circuit>& branch: circ.branches)
        branches.push_back(branch->clone());
}
```

Compile with C++14 or upwards.

Comment: i like to add a `using circuitPtr = std::unique_ptr<circuit>;` since it cuts down visual noise in something like `std::vector<circuitPtr>`

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is available since C++11, but `std::make_unique()` is not available until C++14. In C++11, you can use `return std::unique_ptr<circuit>(new circuit(*this));` instead. In either case, the `for` loops in the copy constructor can use `auto` to make them a little more readable: `for(const auto& component: circ.components) ... for(const auto &branch: circ.branches) ...`